# Blocking in terms of java.io/java.nio

Tags: java, java-io

I just read ...

> Classes that work with streams are located in two packages:
>   java.io and java.nio. Classes from the former implement
>   blocking of input/output (I/O): When bytes are being read/written by a
>   process, they become unavailable for other threads of execution. The
>   latter package offers non-blocking I/O with improved performance.

... and would like to understand this a bit more. Does blocking only impact the single relevant thread, but leave the source (i.e. file or database) itself unblocked, ready to be accessed by other streams? Or does the blocking actually prevent the source from being accessed itself, until the current thread is done with the reading?

Comment: blocking/non-blocking APIs describe the behaviour of the reading thread, not the transmitting source.

Comment: @yurib Okay that's straight to the point. Thank you. So am I correct in presuming that if some other thread wanted to access the source it could also do so without any issues at the same time as the first accessing thread?

Comment: that cannot be said definitively, there could be other factors restricting access to the data source, depending on what the source actually is / what protocol is used. btw EJP gave a complete and precise answer, including the usage of the 'blocking' term. you should read up on the matter since i suspect you lack some basic understanding of what blocking actually means.

Comment: Yes, I lack proper understanding. Would you kindly point me towards any online basic material that will explain the terms blocking and locking?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/TransactionGettingStarted/blocking_deadlocks.html

Comment: @Yurib I think I understand better now, but can you clarify one more thing. With "Non-Blocking I/O", when a thread requests for data, it reads as much as possible and returns immediately to carry on with doing something else. Does this also apply for writing data? If so, I don't understand how. Since writing data would be self initiated, and so there shouldn't be the need for waiting, theoretically. Is this correct?

Comment: If you quote something make sure you cite it correctly. Where did you read this?

Comment: I can look for it again if you really want me to, but is something wrong?

Comment: 'When bytes are being read/written by a process, they become unavailable ...' is complete drivel. Bytes can't 'become unavailable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking basically refers to when a thread invokes a read() or write(), it is blocked from doing anything else until there is some data to read or the data is written. The thread can do NOTHING else in the meantime.

So blocking is to do with the thread itself, not the data source.

Comment: It blocks until the data is transferred to the kernel. 'Fully written' could mean committed to the disk, or the network, which certainly isn't true. Your question had already been answered: no need to prove a mangled version of your own.

Comment: @EJP First of all, thank you! Please know that I appreciated your answer, and certainly did learn from it. In fact, I would have gladly selected your answer as the "solution". However, it did not address my question completely. I wanted to know more about the involvement of the data source, but you mentioned nothing about this. Secondly, as someone who is just learning, being introduced to concepts that I did not ask about only added to my difficulty. For instance, I did not know about or ask about the definition of 'non-blocking'. Anyway, please don't feel hurt. I still appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

'Blocking' means that the I/O method you are calling blocks the calling thread until at least some data has been transferred, or until an accept or connect operation has either succeede or failed.

'Non-blocking' means that if no data can be transferred, the I/O method returns immediately with an appropriate return value or exception, or that a connect operation proceeds in the background and can be checked for completion later.

For completeness, 'asynchronous' means that the I/O method returns immediately but the operation continues in the background, with its result available via another call in due course, or a callback.

Comment: I've told you what the terms mean. The clear implication is that they don't mean anything else. When I said 'blocks' I mean 'blocks'. A lock is a different thing entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a situation where you have 2 threads. Both threads are reading from single socket streams. Here we are concerned about the source bytes which we are reading as well as we need to check in terms of `Multi-threading`. The reason is due to `Blocking I/O`

- Blocking I/O: This is I/O which waits indefinitely for availability of source. The execution of thread waits at that point and it increases chances of `Hang` or `Slowness` of your application. `java.io` package is example of this type
- Non-Blocking I/O:  This is I/O which will not wait for source for infinite time, but will return immediately. `java.nio` package is example of this type

Comment: For example when multiple threads are accessing socket, the blocking may occur and application can show ANR

Comment: A socket read can block with a single thread. Two threads doesn't add anything to that. You're confusing blocking with synchronization.

Comment: Consider we have thread1 and thread2. When thread1 is doing read operation (which is blocking), and at the same time (synchronization concept), thread2 tries to read from same socket. This is situation I have faced